# Regex - Remove a string with regex from regex result

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a strange JSON value that includes curly brackets without quotes. So, I cannot parse it with JSON.parse function in javascript. Is anyone any idea to parse below strange-JSON data? Also, I will accept to replace those curly brackets with something using regex.

Here is my JSON data.

```
`{
    "glossary": {
        "title": ${find_this},
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "${dont_find_this}",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "GlossSeeAlso": [
                            "GML",
                            "XML"
                        ]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": ${find_this_too}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
var JSONStrUnprocessed = `
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": \${find_this},
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "\${dont_find_this}",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "GlossSeeAlso": [
                            "GML",
                            "XML"
                        ]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": \${find_this_too}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
`

var JSONStrProcessed = JSONStrUnprocessed.replace(/(?!")(\$\{[^\}]+\})(?!")/g, '"$1"')
console.log(JSON.parse(JSONStrProcessed))
```